# How to remove dynamic_cast at design level

Tags: c++

Needing `dynamic_cast` is often considered bad design. Then consider this situation:

- 1 abstract base class `ABC`;
- 100 derived classes `D1`, `D2`...`D100`;
- An application handling 100'000 `Ds` objects in realtime;

Those `Ds` objects need to be stored in some container so I store them as `ABC*`.

When I need to search for nodes of a specific type, I would need to `dynamic_cast` them all and return the "good ones". Alternatives to `dynamic_cast` exist but they are more implementation details than strictly design:

- Use a virtual method: `AsD23()` returning a `D23*` if `this` is a `D23*` and `nullptr` otherwise;
- Use a typeId + static_cast;

In both alternatives, the only thing that changes is the way to check that an ABC is actually a `D42` or not. That's why I consider this more an implementation detail than a design choice. **Am I right?**

Then, if yes, and in this particular situation, **what would be a good alternative (if any) in terms of design?**

Comment: Why do you need only objects of a particular type? Seems like they should be stored in a collection by themselves.

Comment: Need to apply X to suitable objects? Have a virtual function that does X or nothing, as opposed to checking whether X is applicable.

Comment: For option one, you could use the visitor pattern to determine and handle the derived types.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: so you propose to use 100 collections, one for each specific type?

Comment: @n.m.: suppose I have 10 specific X per derived class. Then, I should add 1'000 virtual methods to ABC?

Comment: If you use a visitor pattern, there is one additional virtual method in the base class.  But the visitor is a separate class.  It would need a function for each derived class (or at least one for each derived class you would want to extract).  But the function body is trivial.

Comment: If your derived classes are so diverse, it is perhaps unwise to treat them *in this particular context* as subtypes of a common ancestor type. Or maybe if you are ready to write `if (good for Xi) apply Xi` 1000 times, then having 1000 Xi virtual methods isn't any worse. *Some* piece of code needs to know about all these Xi things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to change the container: use [`std::multimap<std::type_index,ABC*>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) (or [`std::unordered_multimap<std::type_index,ABC*>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) if you have access to C++11) to store your objects, using their `type_id` as the key ([`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) warps `type_id`). This way you could get to a particular type very quickly - in logarithmic time with `std::multimap` or in constant time with `std::unordered_multimap` (iterating the actual objects is, of course, linear in the number of objects of a specific class that need to be iterated).

One disadvantage of this approach is its reliance on `type_id`: it lets you get to a specific subclass quickly, but if your type hierarchy becomes more complex in the future, say, you add subclasses of `ABC`, say, `BCD1`, `BCD2`, ...,  that serve as base class of *some* of your derived types, the approach above does not let you search for all objects of `BCDx`, because you need to pass the id of a "final" type, i.e. one of `D...` ones.

Note that using raw pointers in a container is not ideal - consider replacing them with smart pointers, say, `std::unique_ptr<ABC>` or `std::shared_ptr<ABC>`.

Comment: You cannot store `std::type_info` by value. It is not copy-constructable. If you've to use `std::type_info*` (and that is going to work because for a type `T`, the expression `typeid(T)` would *always* return the *same* instance (which means the address will be same)).

Comment: Alright... changed to `std::type_index`. Great. That will work.

Comment: @n.m. Right - the discussion of this shortcoming is the topic of the second paragraph of my answer. However, OP's hierarchy does look flat, so he may be able to take advantage of this approach.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yes, our hierarchy is indeed flat.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: just a small remark. It seems that retrieving values from an unordered_multimap is linear in the worst case and constant in the average case.